# how to toggle the bits of binary representation of a number?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Given a  number, i want to toggle the bits of number 'n' 
say for example if n = 6  -> 0110 
i want to get, result = 9 -> 1001 
toggle , i.e 
convert 1 to 0  & convert 0 to 1 in the binary representation 
how to do this programmatically in java, by doing XOR of num with 1's 
Thanks all for answers, so it depends of how many bits i want to toggle
say for ex, if its 8 bits then 0xff
if its entire 32 bits then oxffffffff
1 way would be `n ^ ~0`

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon this is pretty clear not the logical exclusive operator. Can you find an actual duplicate question?

Comment: the question is not about XOR (exclusive or), it is how to toggle bits using XOR

Comment: I gave an example, but it also depends on how many bits you want to toggle. eg in your example you have limited it to 4 bits. Do you want to use a full integer?

Comment: @matt : yes, thank you, just gave the example of 6, so for entire integer (32 bit) it will be ` n ^ 0xffffffff`

Comment: @src3369 I agree it's not a duplicate and should never have been marked as such, but nevertheless, the way it's worded, this question is too trivial. It's akin to "I know what the plus (+) operator does, but how can I use it to add two numbers together?" If you can reword the question to explain what exactly is causing difficulty, it may get more meaningful answers.

Comment: Maybe you want the ones-complement: `~6 == 0b111...111001` == -6-1 == -7`.

Comment: [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47981/995714)

Comment: Lưu Vĩnh Phúc's link is very useful and, although it's C and C++, it's still relevant to Java. The main differences being that Java doesn't have unsigned ints but instead has the `>>>` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do exactly that.

```
int y = 6^0xf
```

If you want to use the full int, then you have to XOR with -1 (twos complement means this is all 1's).

```
int y = 6^-1;
```

You can also use a different representation to make writing it out more intuitive.

```
int mask = 0xffffffff; //also -1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final int n = 0b0110;
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(n));
        final int m = n ^ 0xffffffff;
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(m));
    }
```

Comment: The XOR will give a different result depending on the number of 1's. In ops example the result is 9, in your example you get -7.